# SwiftUI - Bring variable integer value to other views

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, integer

I made a small quiz. When you press a button an specific amount is added to Xcode and Ycode.
Now I want to take the value of Xcode and Ycode with me to the next view.
So when you are in the next view you can answer another question and an amount is added on top of the existing amount and then I want to take that value to yet another view.

So how could I take the value of Xcode and Ycode to the next view?
This is de code I made:

```
    @State var ShowButton: Bool = false
    @State var ButtonYes: Bool = false
    @State var ButtonNo: Bool = false
    @State var ButtonSometimes: Bool = false
    @State var Xcode = 0
    @State var Ycode = 0

        
var body: some View {
    
        ZStack{
        Image("Chimps")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            VStack{
                Text("Question 1")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                Spacer()
                Text(String(Xcode))
                Text(String(Ycode))
                Text("Question 1")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                
                HStack(spacing:10) {
                    
                    
                Button("Yes") {
                    ShowButton = true
                    ButtonYes.toggle()
                    if ButtonYes == true {
                    Xcode += 5
                        }
                    if ButtonYes == true {
                    Ycode += 5
                        }
                    if ButtonYes == false {
                        Xcode -= 5
                        }
                    if ButtonYes == false {
                        Ycode -= 5
                        }
                    if ButtonNo == true {
                        Xcode -= 3
                    }
                    if ButtonNo == true {
                        Ycode -= 3
                    }
                    if ButtonSometimes == true {
                        Xcode -= 1
                        }
                    if ButtonSometimes == true {
                        Ycode -= 1
                        }
                    if ButtonYes == true {
                        ButtonNo = false
                    }
                    if ButtonYes == true {
                        ButtonSometimes = false
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(ButtonYes ? Color(red: 0.272, green: 0.471, blue: 0.262) : Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                   
                    Button("No") {
                        ShowButton = true
                        ButtonNo.toggle()
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                        Xcode += 3
                            }
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                        Ycode += 3
                            }
                        if ButtonNo == false {
                            Xcode -= 3
                            }
                        if ButtonNo == false {
                            Ycode -= 3
                            }
                        if ButtonYes == true {
                            Xcode -= 5
                        }
                        if ButtonYes == true {
                            Ycode -= 5
                        }
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                            Xcode -= 1
                            }
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                            Ycode -= 1
                            }
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                            ButtonYes = false
                        }
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                            ButtonSometimes = false
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(ButtonNo ? Color(red: 0.272, green: 0.471, blue: 0.262) : Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                    
                    Button("Sometimes") {
                        ShowButton = true
                        ButtonSometimes.toggle()
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                        Xcode += 1
                            }
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                        Ycode += 1
                            }
                        if ButtonSometimes == false {
                            Xcode -= 1
                            }
                        if ButtonSometimes == false {
                            Ycode -= 1
                            }
                        if ButtonYes == true {
                            Xcode -= 5
                        }
                        if ButtonYes == true {
                            Ycode -= 5
                        }
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                            Xcode -= 3
                            }
                        if ButtonNo == true {
                            Ycode -= 3
                            }
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                            ButtonYes = false
                        }
                        if ButtonSometimes == true {
                            ButtonNo = false
                        }
                      
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(ButtonSometimes ? Color(red: 0.272, green: 0.471, blue: 0.262) : Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                if ShowButton {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Question2(),
                
                    label: {
                Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color(red: 0.493, green: 0.184, blue: 0.487))
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 80, alignment: .bottom)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(10)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                        
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Question 2")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                    )}
                
            )
                Spacer()
            }
    }
        
    
}
           
}
}
```

Comment: Use @Binding in the new view

Comment: Thank you for your respons!

I tried to use a binding but run into an error. 

I used "@Binding var Xcode: Int" on the 2th screen. It says:
Missing argument for parameter 'Xcode' in call

Then I put Question2(Xcode: $Xcode) on the first screen.
But I keep running into error.

Can you send me in the right direction?

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and working example of how you could use @Binding on the second screen to update the existing amount. But I would recommend you to take a look on the docs and understand when to use @State, @Binding, @ObservedObject, @StateObject, etc.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    
    @State var xValue = 0
    @State var yValue = 0
           
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(xValue)")
                Text("\(yValue)")
                Button("add to x") {
                    xValue += 1
                }
                Button("add to y") {
                    yValue += 1
                }
                Divider()
                NavigationLink("next screen", destination: SecondView(xValue: $xValue, yValue: $yValue))
            }
        }
    }

}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var xValue: Int
    @Binding var yValue: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(xValue)")
                Text("\(yValue)")
                Button("add to x") {
                    xValue += 1
                }
                Button("add to y") {
                    yValue += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I've been watching multiple videos and reading  about bindings and the other objects you mentioned. I accepted you answer and upvoted it. Again, thank you :)